# Same syntax as : if, for, while

Tags: javascript

I thought of a syntax that could be very helpful :

```
function myFunction(){}
myFunction(){anotherFunction();};
```

I want to have the same result as : http://jsfiddle.net/tMawX/ but a syntax like : http://jsfiddle.net/J9hQp/

Is there a way to do it?

My final goal is to re-write the `for` function so it is wrote like that : `for(0,100){func};` instead of `for(0,100,func);`

Comment: What's wrong with the first way?

Comment: Do you want to know if you can use a syntax that isn't the one of javascript in javascript ? If so, no. But maybe you'd prefer alternatives like CoffeeScript (but I'd recommend to stick to javascript until you're experienced).

Comment: `for` is not a function. Even if it was, `for(0,100){func}` would not be valid Javascript syntax.

Comment: no, i would re-write. It would be `myFor(0,100){func};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CoffeeScript has short syntax for functions:

```
eatMe = (x)-> x(); alert(3);

eatMe -> alert(2)
```

Translates to this:

```
var eatMe;

eatMe = function(x) {
  x();
  return alert(3);
};

eatMe(function() {
   return alert(2);
});
```

Your `for` function would look like:

```
myfor = (from, to) ->
    (callback) ->
        [callback(i) for i in [from..to]]

myfor(1, 3) -> alert('Hooray!')
```